# TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object

Tags: javascript, next.js

am getting a list of more than 1000 numbers from an api and past it to variable called number, i want to get the highest number am getting from the api, this is the Error am gettiing TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object. please i don't know what am doing wrong can someone please help out.

this is my code

```
function CryptoTopGain ({number}){
      let highPercent = Math.max.apply(null, percent);
     console.log(highPercent )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where is the `percent` variable defined.
Or if you used correct variable name, it looks like that issue was occurred by  destructured parameter.

You can like this.

```
function CryptoTopGain (number){
  let highPercent = Math.max.apply(null, number);
 console.log(highPercent )
}

const number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 23, 12, 34, 54, 23, 12]

CryptoTopGain(number)
```

or

```
function CryptoTopGain ({number}){
  let highPercent = Math.max.apply(null, number);
 console.log(highPercent )
}

const number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 23, 12, 34, 54, 23, 12]

CryptoTopGain({number})
```